# Inject a FlowScoped bean into a Jersey REST Web Service

Tags: java, rest, jsf, jersey, cdi

I'm developing an application that use a JSF flow to manage a wizard-like activity that can be started by a logged in user.

One page of the flow needs custom JavaScript code written in AngularJS, so I created a small Jersey REST service to exchange data between AngularJS and the bean (obviously the service should be called only when a user is using that flow page).

Inside the service I need the FlowScoped bean, but if I try to do

```
@Path("rest")
@RequestScoped
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    MyFlowScopedBean myFlowScopedBean;

    // ...
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
exception java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIContext.getCurrentFlow
```

So, I'm using a session scoped bean associated to the user to retrieve the bean using the following workaround:

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("myFlow")
public class MyFlowScopedBean {

    @Inject
    UserDataBean userDataBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userDataBean.setMyFlowScopedBean(this);
    }

    // ...
}

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserDataBean {

    private MyFlowScopedBean myFlowScopedBean;

    public getMyFlowScopedBean() {
        return myFlowScopedBean;
    }
    public setMyFlowScopedBean(MyFlowScopedBean myFlowScopedBean) {
        this.myFlowScopedBean = myFlowScopedBean;
    }

    // ...
}

@Path("rest")
@RequestScoped
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    UserDataBean userDataBean;

    private MyFlowScopedBean getMyFlowScopedBean() {
        return userDataBean.getMyFlowScopedBean();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? And, more important, should I do this or am I violating some best practices/conventions?

(I'm deploying on Glassfish 4.1)

Thanks!

Comment: JAX-RS and JSF are completely independent frameworks having their own different purposes and cannot communicate with each other in anyway on the server side. The design is flopped and may need to be reconsidered.

Comment: I saw various examples of CDI and Rest services mixed (also in a JBoss Weld book there is a final chapter dedicated to AngularJS). I only need that one page of my flow use JavaScript+REST instead of JSF approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using JSF `FlowScoped` it is possible to obtain something very similar using [`ConversationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html).

From the book "JBoss Weld CDI for Java Platform" by Ken Finnigan:

> The conversation context implementation within Weld was developed to be used specifically with JSF. [...] In CDI 1.1, the tight coupling with JSF will be removed, enabling the conversation context to be used with other web frameworks.

Here a minimal working example (inspired by [this blog post](http://www.knitelius.com/2015/07/22/cdi-conversations-for-jax-rs-with-jee-6/)):

```
@Named("foo")
@ConversationScoped
public class FooBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    Conversation conversation;

    public String getConversationId() {
        return conversation.getId();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        conversation.begin();
    }

    // ...
}

@Path("foo")
@ConversationScoped
public class FooResource implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    FooBean fooBean;

    @GET
    @Path("myMethod")
    public String myMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In .xhtml:

```
<script>
    var CID = '#{foo.conversationId}'; // <-- EL
    $.get('/myApp/foo/myMethod?cid=' + CID);
</script>
```

**Warning**: pay attention using `@FormParam`: grizzly [seems to have problems](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1822) with it.

If you want a complete example about creating wizard using the conversation scope take a look at [this post](http://blog.goyello.com/2011/06/08/jee6-cdi-and-conversation-scope/).